# How to extract Tiles position to check with player`s position?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to create a script (2D game)which can detect Player collision with tile from Tilemap named "Middle" and slow player. Problem is I dont know how to extract Tiles position from Tilemap in c# script.

Can i check that Player position and Tiles positions?

Comment: Hi, Stackoverflow works best when you try stuff, it doesn't work, you share the code, and *then* we comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a trigger that encompasses the region that you want to slow player on and have one method in the player move script that lowers the player move speed and is called on entering the trigger and one that increases the player move speed and is called when exiting the trigger instead of positioning. I would also look into terrain and how you might use it with tile maps